# Generating text in a new fragment based on Firebase getRef()

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a listview that generates a list of clubs in Edinburgh including an image, title and special deals. When a user clicks on the club they wish to  see more about a new fragment opens and is populated by data about that club. I was able to get the correct child name using getRef() and output this to a toast, the question is how to I make it that when the user clicks the list my textViews are automatically populated with the corresponding data?

This is my ClubList fragment

```
public class ClubListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView clubList;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public ClubListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_club_list, container, false);


        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("clubs");

        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);


        //declare and populate the clublist view
        clubList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lstClub_List);
        clubList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        clubList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Clubs, ClubListHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Clubs, ClubListHolder>(

            Clubs.class,
            R.layout.club_row,
            ClubListHolder.class,
            mDatabase


        ) 
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ClubListHolder viewHolder, Clubs model, int position) {

                final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setOpen(model.getOpen());
                viewHolder.setDesc1("*" + model.getDesc1());
                viewHolder.setDesc2("*" + model.getDesc2());
                viewHolder.setDesc3("*" + model.getDesc3());
                viewHolder.setImage(getActivity(), model.getImage());

                viewHolder.nView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), post_key , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        ClubInfoFragment fragment = new ClubInfoFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        clubList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class ClubListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View nView;

        public ClubListHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {

            TextView club_title = (TextView) nView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            club_title.setText(title);

        }

        public void setOpen(String open) {

            //finds day of the week and converts it to a string
            String day;
            SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.UK);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            day = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            //find the Open/Closed Today TextView
            TextView club_open = (TextView) nView.findViewById(R.id.txtOpen);

            //parses the database for a day that macthes the current day, if found then...
            if (open.contains(day)){
                club_open.setText("Open Today");
                ((TextView) nView.findViewById(R.id.txtOpen)).setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }

            //else do this
            else
            {
                club_open.setText("Closed Today");
                ((TextView) nView.findViewById(R.id.txtOpen)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }

        public void setDesc1(String desc1) {

            TextView club_desc1 = (TextView) nView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc1);
            club_desc1.setText(desc1);

        }

        public void setDesc2(String desc2) {

            TextView club_desc2 = (TextView) nView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc2);
            club_desc2.setText(desc2);

        }

        public void setDesc3(String desc3) {

            TextView club_desc3 = (TextView) nView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc3);
            club_desc3.setText(desc3);

        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image) {

            ImageView club_image = (ImageView) nView.findViewById(R.id.imgClub);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(club_image);
        }
    }

}
```

Should I somehow save the Firebase Reference and make it a global variable to then be used in a new fragment or is there a way to do it from my ClubListFragment?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it using arguments to your `ClubInfoFragment:`

```
Bundle clubObjBundle=new Bundle();
clubObjBundle.putSerializable("mymodel",model);
ClubInfoFragment fragment = new ClubInfoFragment();
fragment.setArguments(clubObjBundle);
FragmentTransaction ft=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                    ft.commit();
```

In your `ClubInfoFragment's` oncreate method you can get all details without making another firebase call.

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if(getArguments!=null){
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    Clubs model=(Clubs)bundle.getSerializable("mymodel");
 }


  /*call and use your setTitle,setDesc1 etc on model object */


}
```

Also make sure your `Clubs` class implements `Serializable`

```
public class Clubs implements Serializable {`

 /*keep content as it is*/

}
```